# Убрать последний символ с QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qlineedit

Хочу чтобы при срабатывании функции из QLineEdit убирался последний символ, но не знаю как это осуществить

Вот код:

> **WARNING:** Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is run again.  
> **Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 510)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 510))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_data = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 321, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.input_data.setFont(font)
        self.input_data.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(164, 218, 158);\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.input_data.setText("")
        self.input_data.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.input_data.setObjectName("input_data")
        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button7.setFont(font)
        self.button7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.button7.setObjectName("button7")
        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button8.setFont(font)
        self.button8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button8.setObjectName("button8")
        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button9.setFont(font)
        self.button9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button9.setObjectName("button9")
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button4.setFont(font)
        self.button4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button5.setFont(font)
        self.button5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button6.setFont(font)
        self.button6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
        self.buttonpoint = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonpoint.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonpoint.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonpoint.setFont(font)
        self.buttonpoint.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonpoint.setObjectName("buttonpoint")
        self.button0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 380, 81, 81))
        self.button0.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button0.setFont(font)
        self.button0.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button0.setObjectName("button0")
        self.buttonc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonc.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonc.setFont(font)
        self.buttonc.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonc.setObjectName("buttonc")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button1.setFont(font)
        self.button1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button2.setFont(font)
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button3.setFont(font)
        self.button3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
        self.buttonsub = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonsub.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 300, 81, 81))
        self.buttonsub.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonsub.setFont(font)
        self.buttonsub.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonsub.setObjectName("buttonsub")
        self.buttondiv = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttondiv.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 220, 81, 81))
        self.buttondiv.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttondiv.setFont(font)
        self.buttondiv.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttondiv.setObjectName("buttondiv")
        self.buttonmult = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonmult.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 140, 81, 81))
        self.buttonmult.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonmult.setFont(font)
        self.buttonmult.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonmult.setObjectName("buttonmult")
        self.buttonadd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonadd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonadd.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 162))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonadd.setFont(font)
        self.buttonadd.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonadd.setObjectName("buttonadd")
        self.buttonequally = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonequally.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 460, 321, 50))
        self.buttonequally.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.buttonequally.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonequally.setFont(font)
        self.buttonequally.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonequally.setObjectName("buttonequally")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


        self.get_data()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.button8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.button9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.button4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.button5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.button6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.buttonpoint.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "."))
        self.button0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.buttonc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "с"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.buttonsub.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.buttondiv.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.buttonmult.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.buttonadd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.buttonequally.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))

    def get_data(self):
        self.button0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button0.text()))
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button1.text()))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button2.text()))
        self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button3.text()))
        self.button4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button4.text()))
        self.button5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button5.text()))
        self.button6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button6.text()))
        self.button7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button7.text()))
        self.button8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button8.text()))
        self.button9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button9.text()))
        self.buttonadd.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonadd.text()))
        self.buttondiv.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttondiv.text()))
        self.buttonsub.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonsub.text()))
        self.buttonmult.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonmult.text()))
        self.buttonequally.clicked.connect(self.rep())
        self.buttonpoint.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonpoint.text()))
        self.buttonc.clicked.connect(self.clean)



    def write_number(self, number):
        self.input_data.setText(self.input_data.text() + number)

    def clean(self):
        self.input_data.setText('')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ** код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, **НИКОГДА**. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

Примерно так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 510)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(320, 510))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_data = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 321, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.input_data.setFont(font)
        self.input_data.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(164, 218, 158);\n"
"color: #ffffff;\n"
"border: none;")
        self.input_data.setText("")
        self.input_data.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.input_data.setObjectName("input_data")
        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button7.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button7.setFont(font)
        self.button7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.button7.setObjectName("button7")
        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button8.setFont(font)
        self.button8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button8.setObjectName("button8")
        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 140, 81, 81))
        self.button9.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button9.setFont(font)
        self.button9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button9.setObjectName("button9")
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button4.setFont(font)
        self.button4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button4.setObjectName("button4")
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button5.setFont(font)
        self.button5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button5.setObjectName("button5")
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 220, 81, 81))
        self.button6.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button6.setFont(font)
        self.button6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button6.setObjectName("button6")
        self.buttonpoint = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonpoint.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonpoint.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonpoint.setFont(font)
        self.buttonpoint.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonpoint.setObjectName("buttonpoint")
        self.button0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 380, 81, 81))
        self.button0.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button0.setFont(font)
        self.button0.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button0.setObjectName("button0")
        self.buttonc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonc.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonc.setFont(font)
        self.buttonc.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonc.setObjectName("buttonc")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button1.setFont(font)
        self.button1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button2.setFont(font)
        self.button2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button2.setObjectName("button2")
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 300, 81, 81))
        self.button3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.button3.setFont(font)
        self.button3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(119, 204, 136);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.button3.setObjectName("button3")
        self.buttonsub = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonsub.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 300, 81, 81))
        self.buttonsub.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonsub.setFont(font)
        self.buttonsub.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonsub.setObjectName("buttonsub")
        self.buttondiv = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttondiv.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 220, 81, 81))
        self.buttondiv.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttondiv.setFont(font)
        self.buttondiv.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttondiv.setObjectName("buttondiv")
        self.buttonmult = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonmult.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 140, 81, 81))
        self.buttonmult.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonmult.setFont(font)
        self.buttonmult.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonmult.setObjectName("buttonmult")
        self.buttonadd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonadd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 380, 81, 81))
        self.buttonadd.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(81, 162))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonadd.setFont(font)
        self.buttonadd.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonadd.setObjectName("buttonadd")
        self.buttonequally = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.buttonequally.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 460, 321, 50))
        self.buttonequally.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 50))
        self.buttonequally.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.buttonequally.setFont(font)
        self.buttonequally.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: #ffffff;\n"
"    background-color: rgb(67, 187, 116);\n"
"    border-radius: 0px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(59, 185, 121);\n"
"}")
        self.buttonequally.setObjectName("buttonequally")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.button8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.button9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.button4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.button5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.button6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.buttonpoint.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "."))
        self.button0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.buttonc.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "с"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.button2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.button3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.buttonsub.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.buttondiv.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.buttonmult.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.buttonadd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.buttonequally.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.backspaceButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Backspace", self.centralwidget)       # !!!
        self.backspaceButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 460, 90, 50))
        self.backspaceButton.clicked.connect(self.backspaceClicked)                         # !!!
        

        self.button0.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button0.text()))
        self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button1.text()))
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button2.text()))
        self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button3.text()))
        self.button4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button4.text()))
        self.button5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button5.text()))
        self.button6.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button6.text()))
        self.button7.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button7.text()))
        self.button8.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button8.text()))
        self.button9.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.button9.text()))
        self.buttonadd.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonadd.text()))
        self.buttondiv.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttondiv.text()))
        self.buttonsub.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonsub.text()))
        self.buttonmult.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonmult.text()))
        
#        self.buttonequally.clicked.connect(self.rep())
        self.buttonequally.clicked.connect(self.rep)                                           # !!!
        
        self.buttonpoint.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write_number(self.buttonpoint.text()))
        self.buttonc.clicked.connect(self.clean)

    def write_number(self, number):
        self.input_data.setText(self.input_data.text() + number)

    def clean(self):
        self.input_data.setText('')

    def rep(self):        
        pass
        
    def backspaceClicked(self):                                                                # !!!
        text = self.input_data.text()
        if not text:
            text = '0'
        else:
            text = self.input_data.text()[:-1]
            if not text:
                text = '0'
        self.input_data.setText(text)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но после компиляции кода из .ui в .py я ничего не менял в коде. Я просто добавил функции которые вывяд значения кнопок в LineEdit

Comment: @ЗахарУляшов Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.